# How can I assign keys to existing values in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I recovered an array with values from a previous method and I need to go through it and assign each of the values a key in alphabetical order.

```
["T", "C", "α", "T(linked)", "C"]
```

This is my array, previously mentioned. I want to know how, when crossing the array will I be able to assign it a key of alphabetical form, so that the final result was:

```
["A:T", "B:C", "C:α", "D:T(linked), "E:C"]
```

Any advice will be welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want an array of elements like this `"A:T"`, this is string, not an object. You said you want to assign keys, that does not make any sense.

Comment: You should say I want to modify array elements in `"key:value"` form. where `key` is in alphabetical order as shown below.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm a beginner and I'm still a little insecure about the terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `Array.prototype.map` function.

```js
let a = ["T", "C", "α", "T(linked)", "C"];

a = a.map((val,index)=>{ return `${String.fromCharCode(65 + index )}:${val}`; } ) ;

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

By having single elements, you could just map the values with a prefix.

```js
var data = ["T", "C", "α", "T(linked)", "C"],
    result = data.map((v, i) => `${(i + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase()}:${v}`);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your input array:

```
["T, C", "α", "T(linked), C"]
```

are "T, C" and "T(linked), C" supposed to be elements as is, or are you missing quotation marks? In other words, did you mean this?

```
["T", "C", "α", "T(linked)", "C"]
```

You can use the map function. Using the code

```
newArray = array.map((value, index) => ...)
```

will generate a new array with a function done for each value and index of the old array.

```
array = ["T", "C", "α", "T(linked)", "C"];
newArray = array.map((value, index) => `${String.fromCharCode(index + 65)}:${value}`);
```

newArray will be set to

```
["A:T", "B:C", "C:α", "D:T(linked)", "E:C"]
```

If you don't understand that method of concatenating strings, use this instead.

```
array = ["T", "C", "α", "T(linked)", "C"];
newArray = array.map((value, index) => String.fromCharCode(index + 65) + ":" + value);
```

Comment: "T, C" and "T(linked), C" are supposed to be elements. 
perfect, this works ! thank you so much!